# Adding days to dates in scala

Tags: scala

I have created a method that is able to write `15.jan, 4.feb, 20.dec`, and so on to create LocalDate objects that represent dates in the current year.

```
object DateImplicits {

 import DateImplicits._
 import java.time.LocalDate
 import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit


  implicit class RichDate(day:Int){
    def jan():LocalDate = LocalDate.of(2016,1,day)
    def jan(year:Int):LocalDate = LocalDate.of(year,1,day)
        def feb():LocalDate = LocalDate.of(2016,2,day)....}
}
```

However, I am trying to write a method that can add days/months/years to the dates.

in other words,  if x is a LocalDate, I should be able to add days, months, and years in
the following way: `x + 10.days, x + 2.months, and x + 5.years`.

I know that I  need to two implicit classes but I am not sure how to go about filling the method. There's a post that gives a clue, but I am still lost:

```
implicit class RichLocalDate(d:LocalDate) =???

implicit class RichInt(n:Int) = ???
```

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You have done all most of things, You just need to create `implicit class` for `LocalDate` too(same as `implicit class Int`), like:

```
  implicit class RichLocalDate(d:LocalDate) {
    def +(d2: LocalDate) = ... //overloadding for +
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need an implicit class for the  integer.day/month/year as well?

Comment: I think you should, if you want to bind `day`, `month`, `year` method in `Int class`, you should also keep the `Int implicit class`

Comment: So something like implicit class RichInt(n:Int) = def ??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this yourself, you could also use https://github.com/reactivecodes/scala-time which already provides this.